# Extracting XML element text based on node attribute in Python 3

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am trying to extract various information from an XML file.  I am able to partially collect information, but I am having difficulties walking the element tree as some nodes have the same name and I am having to extract based on attribute name within the child node.

Here's the XML snippet:

```
<parent_element>
    <test_case name="00001d" run="1">
      <properties>
        <item name="ID">001029d</item>
        <item name="Test Description">Usefull Information</item>
      </properties>
      <runner>
        <iteration name="First Iter"/>
        <iteration name="1">
          <inputs>
            <input name="FirstInput">005546</input>
          </inputs>
          <step name="Setup"/>
          <step name="1">
            <action actual="0x00 01 1E" msg="INTERESTING.TAG" type="SET"/>
            <action actual="9" msg="TAG.LENGTH" type="SET"/>
            <action actual="10 10 01" msg="SOMETHING.RESULT" type="SET"/>
            <action actual="11 10 01" msg="OTHER.TYPE" type="SET"/>
          </step>
          <step name="ENDING"/>
        </iteration>
        <iteration name="TEST_END"/>
      </runner>
    </test_case>
</parent_element>
```

And here's my code so far:

```
import lxml.etree as et 

doc = et.parse('C:/temp/report.xml')

testTags = doc.xpath('//test_case')
actionTags = doc.xpath('//test_case/runner/iteration/step')

for test in testTags:
    propertyTags = test.xpath('properties')
    for prop in propertyTags:
        print (prop[0].text)
        print(prop[1].text)
    for action in actionTags:   
        #print(action[0].text)
        #print(action[1].text)
```

I can easily grab the properties text ('001029d' and 'Usefull Information') but I have commented out where I am stuck in the above code.

I basically need to make a reference to the 'msg=' attribute (e.g. "INTERESTING.TAG") and extract the 'actual=' attribute text (e.g. 0x00 01 1E).  Or is there a much more efficient method I am missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import lxml.etree as et 

doc = et.parse('C:/temp/report.xml')

testTags = doc.xpath('//test_case')

for test in testTags:
  propertyTags = test.xpath('properties')
  actionTags = test.xpath('/runner/iteration/step/action')
  for prop in propertyTags:
      print (prop[0].text)
      print(prop[1].text)
  for action in actionTags:
     msg= action.attrib.get('msg')
     actual = action.attrib.get('actual')
     if msg=="INTERESTING.TAG" or msg=="SOMETHING.RESULT" :
        print(msg)
        print(actual)
```

*caveat* I dont know python, apolgies of the syntax is incorrect.

you could also include a change the xpath to filter the size of actionTags,

```
  actionTags = test.xpath('/runner/iteration/step/action[@msg="INTERESTING.TAG" or @msg="SOMETHING.RESULT"]')
  for prop in propertyTags:
      print (prop[0].text)
      print(prop[1].text)
  for action in actionTags:
     msg= action.attrib.get('msg')
     actual = action.attrib.get('actual')
     print(msg)
     print(actual)
```

Comment: Hi Phil B, ideally I need to make some check with the 'msg=' attribute first as there could be 50+ action entries, and then extract the text in the 'actual=' attribute, additionally the action node may not always be in position 'action[x]'.

Comment: Are you always looking for the same contast msg value?

Comment: Yes, I will be looking for both msg="INTERESTING.TAG" and msg="SOMETHING.RESULT" for each 'test_case'.  So in the above example I am hoping to get '0x00 01 1E' and '10 10 01'

Comment: I changed my answer - hopefully it gives you want you need or at the very least, point you in the right direction.

Comment: Great, thanks Phil B, I used your 'xpath + [msg OR msg]' solution, this looks to be what I was looking for.